# typescript object value extends type

Tags: typescript

How to define extension of type I now have:

```
type FooMap = {[key: string]: Foo<any>};
```

but rather need something like:

```
type FooMap = {[key: string]: E extends Foo<any>};
```

Comment: Can you provide an example as to what `Foo<any>` will not do that you expect this `E extends Foo<any>` to do ?

Comment: it is quite too much complicated, is it possible to define extension fo type?

Comment: You can do interesting things in the type system, `E extends Foo<any>` as such is not one of them. Basic OOP dictates that if you have a variable defined as `let o: Foo<any>` `o` can be `Foo<any>` or any type for which `Foo<any>` is a base-type, so I am not sure what value you can assign to `Foo<any>` that you don't want to be assignable to `Foo<any>`.

Comment: This question would really benefit from a [mcve] that demonstrates what you want to work and what you want not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use generic type argument to define type which extends but not is exactly a specific type.

```
type FooMap<E extends Foo<any>> = {[key: string]: E };
```

Comment: hi, yes i tried it like that and guess it didnt work. i will try it again. problem is when you then have x: FooMap you need to define the type E which is agains the idea. it then goes from left to right not from right to left.

Comment: it compiles, so it depends what is your goal here.